# get most recent rows stored in related tables using django

Tags: python, django, models

I am new to django. Is there a way to get most recent rows (stored into the database during the last transaction) stored in related tables from the database by inqury models using django?

The models are quite general, and using django models to store data in postgresql. In each table, suppose there is no timestamp field, or automatically increasing id field. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields ?

Comment: There is automatically increading ID field.

Comment: what about during one write one table got written in new rows, but another table does not have new rows written in. This is possible for many to many relations. Also another case is that the primary key is specified, which is not an automated increasing integer?

Comment: @baron a more specific example might be useful here. There may be solutions to your problem that don't involve the database. That said, you probably want manually managed transactions if you'd like to query the database while related tables are being created. Normally django wraps entire views in transactions, therefore your m2m fields aren't committed until the view completes.